# Ios Contact Backup which file extension we need to save

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

I am creating a contact backup app, but I have no Idea How to backup the contact and in which extension I need to save it, because In android It will be save in .vcf extension could someone explain on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vcf for both iOS and Android. I did like that in my application:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/power-contacts-pro/id1098817812?mt=8

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can u share any sample coding for taking backup of contact

Answer (score 0):

**ios Devices supports vcf format for saving contact backup.**

for more detail check this link: http://www.ephpod.com/easy-iphone-contacts-backup/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can u share any sample coding for taking backup of contact